# How to update every package on NixOS?

Tags: nixos

Finally figured out how to set up my systems a couple months ago, and have been using them happily ever since, but realized that it's time to update stuff. My NixOS setup involves [declarative package management](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-declarative-package-mgmt) using [Home Manager](https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager), but completely forgot the basics and wasn't sure if Home Manager would complicate things as the [repo](https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager) only mentions the `home-manager` tool which I don't have.

Comment: [Originally posted this on Stackoverflow](https://web.archive.org/web/20201114163813/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835847/how-to-update-every-package-on-nixos) but got closed and deleted as off-topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TL;DR

0. **Are you on the latest channel?**
   (See how to check and set below.)
1. **`sudo nix-channel --update`**
2. a. (declarative/NixOS) **`sudo nixos-rebuild switch`**
   b.                   (ad-hoc) **`nix-env -u '*'`**
   c.     (Home Manager) **`home-manager switch`** ([I think](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/home-manager-equivalent-of-apt-upgrade/8424))

These steps should work regardless of using NixOS or not.

<sup>NOTE-1 (**flakes**): It's a fairly good bet that none of this will work if you are using flakes.</sup>

<sup>NOTE-2 (**NixOS** + **Home Manager**): *If `nixos-rebuild switch` fails with cryptic error messages, look at your Home Manager config.* At least, in the past 5 years, whenever the error wasn't clear (e.g., `nix.maxJobs` deprecated in favor of `nix.settings.max-jobs`), it was always something about Home Manager.</sup>

#### Step 0. Check and set the latest channel

Step 1.'s `nix-channel --update` will only pull the changes in the channel that is **currently set**! To check the current one you are subscribed to, issue

```
sudo nix-channel --list
```

The latest NixOS manual's [Chapter 4. Upgrading NixOS](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/#sec-upgrading) will always show the name and the link of the latest channel. The [Nix Channel Status page](https://status.nixos.org/) is also a very good resource.

For example, I was subscribed to channel `20.09` so I needed to update it to `21.11` by doing

```
$ sudo nix-channel --list
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-20.09

$ sudo nix-channel --remove nixos
$ sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-21.11 nixos
```

More info:

- The Nix manual's [4.4 Channels](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/package-management/channels.html) section is a short intro to Nix channels.
- The NixOS wiki's [Nix channels](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_channels) article goes more into the details and has a good summary on the basic commands. (Personally, I found this one more useful.)

#### Step 1. Update the channel

This is required both for declarative and "ad-hoc" [sic] setups<sup>**3**</sup>:

```
sudo nix-channel --update
```

Even though the Nix manual has a [4.1 Basic Package Management](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/package-management/basic-package-mgmt.html) section, it is best documented in the NixOS manual (see [Chapter 7. Package Management](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-package-management)). (Albeit, I didn't find it straightforward figuring out the correct order of steps from these; the biggest help was [this NixOS discourse thread](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-upgrade-packages/6151).)

Home Manager does not seem to complicate this process. (At least, I'm using it on NixOS, and `nixos-rebuild switch` always takes care of everything with [my setup](https://github.com/toraritte/nixos-config/blob/master/configuration.nix).)

> TIP FOR NIXOS USERS
> The `nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade` combines Step 1. and Step 2. as it "*[is equivalent to the more verbose `nix-channel --update nixos; nixos-rebuild switch`](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-upgrading:%7E:text=%23%20nixos%2Drebuild%20switch%20%2D%2Dupgrade,.)*".

#### Step 2. Update the packages

The two adjectives, "ad-hoc" [sic] and "declarative", are introduced in the [NixOS manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/) to differentiate the two modes of Nix package management<sup>**3**</sup>:

- "**ad-hoc**": Managing packages with `nix-env`.<sup>**1**</sup>
- "**declarative**": In the [NixOS manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/), this refers to declaring packages as a list in NixOS' [`configuration.nix`](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-changing-config), but it can be done in many other ways<sup>**2**</sup>.

The commands:

a. To update all packages declared in NixOS' `configuration.nix`, use:

```
sudo nixos-rebuild switch
```

b. To update all packages installed with `nix-env`:

```
nix-env -u '*'
```

c. To update all packages installed using Home Manager:

```
home-manager switch
```

(I think. Again, I'm using Home Manager in NixOS, and never had to touch any Home Manager commands. See [Home-manager equivalent of “apt upgrade”](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/home-manager-equivalent-of-apt-upgrade/8424))

---

#### Footnotes

[1]: As far as I know, the [NixOS manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/) is the only official document that uses the term "ad-hoc [sic] package management" and only to mean package management using `nix-env`.

(Therefore I find the term misleading, because using packages via `nix-shell -p` commands or custom `shell.nix`-es are also ad hoc forms of package management. Also, [`nix-env` can be messy](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/depreciate-the-use-of-nix-env-to-install-packages/20139).)

[2]: For example with Home Manager, using `shell.nix`-es, flakes. (It is probably incorrect to list flakes, as it is a mechanism that can be used with Home Manager and nix-shell Nix expressions...)

[3]: Not sure if there is a consensus what "ad-hoc", "declarative", and "imperative" package management means in Nix; footnote 1 has my thoughts about "ad-hoc", [some say that using channels is always an imperative form of package management](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/home-manager-equivalent-of-apt-upgrade/8424/2), so "declarative" seems to be overloaded...